# The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Object' from streamtransformer

Tags: flutter

Im following a tutorial and here is original code which is without any error:

```
  static StreamTransformer transformer<T>(
      T Function(Map<String, dynamic> json) fromJson) =>
      StreamTransformer<DataSnapshot, List<T>>.fromHandlers(
        handleData: (DataSnapshot data, EventSink<List<T>> sink) {
          final snaps = data.value.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList(); // there is no map
          final objects = snaps.map((json) => fromJson(json)).toList();// there is no map

          sink.add(objects);
        },
      );
```

and when I copy paste to my code, and here is the error: The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Object', could you please let me know why it happens or what can I do to exchange? thanks !

Comment: If you can share the tutorial link, please do so in order to help you.

Comment: here is the link  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EV2DyrKOqrY&t=650s&ab_channel=JohannesMilke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have the repo link: https://github.com/JohannesMilke/todo_app_firestore_example

It has the same issue you have:
https://github.com/JohannesMilke/todo_app_firestore_example/issues/1

In utils.dart replace it with:

```
static StreamTransformer transformer(
T Function(Map<String, dynamic> json) fromJson) =>
StreamTransformer<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, List>.fromHandlers(
handleData: (QuerySnapshot <Map<String, dynamic>> data, EventSink<List> sink) {
final snaps = data.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
final objects = snaps.map((json) => fromJson(json)).toList();
sink.add(objects);
},
);
```

In firebaseApi.dart replace it with:

```
static Stream<List> readTodos() => FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('todo')
.orderBy(TodoField.createdTime, descending: true)
.snapshots()
.transform(Utils.transformer(Todo.fromJson)
as StreamTransformer<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, List>);
```

Comment: Dear Juan, thank you so much for this info! Now im trying to use firebase database instead of firestore... could you please show me how to create the same methode but with firebase database in firebaseApi.